# Why does my macro only work once?

Tags: vba, excel, excel-2010

It does it correctly the first time, but as soon as I click the button assigned, or run the macro, it just adds another in Rows(6:6), which is a duplicate of Rows (5:5). Any help will be much appreciated.

Please note that it works fine when I remove activesheet.unprotect and activesheet.protect

```
 Sheets("Template").Select
    Rows("1:21").Select
    Selection.Copy
    Sheets("Weekly Plan").Select
    ActiveSheet.Unprotect
    Rows("6:6").Select
    Range("B6").Activate
    Selection.Insert Shift:=xlDown
    Range("K10").Select
    Range("K28:K47").Select
    Range("K47").Activate
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Selection.Copy
    Range("K7").Select
    ActiveSheet.Paste
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    ActiveSheet.Protect
```

Comment: @mehow it works fine when I remove activesheet.unprotect and activesheet.protect

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Would it work this way?

```
Sheets("Weekly Plan").Select
ActiveSheet.Unprotect 
Sheets("Template").Select
Rows("1:21").Select
Selection.Copy
Rows("6:6").Select
Range("B6").Activate
Selection.Insert Shift:=xlDown
Sheets("Weekly Plan").Select
Range("K10").Select
Range("K28:K47").Select
Range("K47").Activate
Application.CutCopyMode = False
Selection.Copy
Range("K7").Select
ActiveSheet.Paste
Application.CutCopyMode = False
ActiveSheet.Protect
```